# I repotted my dracaena marginata in an oversized pot. Now that I know this is incorrect, should I repot it again to a smaller pot?

Tags: container-gardening, roots, dracaena

I have a dracaena that was seriously rootbound in a 10-12 inch container. (That's the approximate size; I can't remember it exactly now). In March of this year, I untangled its roots and repotted it into a container that's 17 in high and 18 in in diameter. It seemed too big so I only planted it about 1/2 - 3/4 of the way up; there isn't a huge amount of soil on the bottom. It had transplant shock and lost some lower leaves on the bottom of its different "trunks," but it has bounced back after a few weeks and and looks good now!

However I now realize the risk of root rot in repotting it in an oversized container. Also, a secondary worry is that it might now grow/expand to its potential because so much energy is going toward its roots. Should I be proactive and repot it? Even if it's doing fine for now? Or is it okay because it's sitting lower in the pot? I really don't want root rot.

Thanks!

[image: whole plant]
[image: close up of leaves]
[image: inside planter]

Answer (score 1):

I have killed more Dracaena Marginata than I care to recall with overwatering.  The roots are thick and the plant is used to full sun outdoors in drier climates.

Indoors in a large pot I would expect the plant not to put on a lot of top growth as the roots will expand into the new pot.

If you leave it in the larger pot I recommend:

- move to the highest light location you have
- water at longer intervals and only when the top two inches of soil is dry
- watch for the usual problems: [spider mites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_mite), [false spider mites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brevipalpus_phoenicis). Symptoms: leaves go yellow and fall off or the center of new growth goes pale